# wordpress website lost styles by itself

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Is it possible, that I made one simple row changes on wordpress wp-config.php
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); to define('DB_CHARSET', '');` 
and website lost its styles and sidebars. I was also worked on plugin, has made no changes to website styles, only on my plugin. I was also deactivated plugin, to understand if it is from it. But nothing. I am confused. I have never made backup of website, and now I can't get it back, that would be very bad.
How could that happened if I made only the charset change for all website?

Comment: Code doesn't change / alter / delete / write itself, one of your changes (or some one else?) made, caused this.

Comment: You shouldn't do such thing. DB_CHARSET reference the db collation, not the website charset. Wordpress probably fail to unserialize some theme / plugin settings if the db collate is wrong.

Comment: @vard thanks for clarification, but is there any way to get it back, unsarialize and serialize it again maybe? I just don't know how the old serilized data was look, and don't know how was the data constructed.

Comment: Well, why did you want to change the DB collation in the first place? If you change back to `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8')` you should have the styles back, no?